# What function solves $f(z)' f(z)^* = 1$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives

I am trying to find the complex function $f(z)$ who's derivative equals the complex conjugate of its reciprocal

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d} f(z)}{\mathrm{d} z} = \dfrac{1}{f(z)^*}$$

which is equivalent to

$$ f(z)' f(z)^* = 1 $$

I know that for $f(z)' f(z) = 1$ the solution is simply $\pm \sqrt{2 z + c }$. But the above turns out to be a bit trickier...

Comment: Why are you using the notation for partial derivative when your function is a function of a single variable?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If we only assume $f$ is say real-analytic $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ instead of holomorphic $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You could take $$f(z) = \pm \sqrt{2 z + c },$$ where $z\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that every real function is complex. (But that's probably not what you are looking for.)

Answer (score 2):

(I shall use the notation $\overline{z}$ to denote the conjugate of $z$. I will assume that your equation is defined on a nonempty open subset $\Omega \subset \Bbb C$.)

There is no such $f$.

Indeed, suppose that such an $f$ existed. Then, your equation forces $f'$ and $\bar{f}$ to be nowhere vanishing on $\Omega$. In particular, we have $$\overline f = \frac{1}{f'}$$
on the open set $\Omega$. Now, since holomorphic functions on open sets are infinitely differentiable, we see that $1/f'$ is differentiable and hence, $\overline{f}$ is differentiable on $\Omega$.

However, if $f$ and $\overline{f}$ are both holomorphic on $\Omega$, then so are $f \pm \overline{f}$. But these take values along the lines $\Bbb R$ and $\iota \Bbb R$. So, both of these are (locally) constant. In turn, $f$ is constant on (the connected components of) $\Omega$.

Thus, $f' \equiv 0$ on $\Omega$. However, since $\Omega \neq \varnothing$, pick $\omega \in \Omega$ and put it in your functional equation to get $0 = 1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function, at least if its domain is a non-empty open subset $D$ of $\Bbb C$. Suppose otherwise. Take $w\in D$ and take $r>0$ such that $D_r(w)\subset D$. Then, on $D_r(w)$, $f'$ is an analytic function and the so is $f'$. But $f'=1\left/\overline f\right.$. So, $\overline f$ is analytic too. But the only case in which $f$ and $\overline f$ are analytic is when $f$ is constant. But then $f'$ is the null function, and therefore it cannot be equal to $1\left/\overline f\right.$.